# How to call a smart contract on any chain without code?

Tags: contract-invocation

Is there a tool that allows making calls to smart contracts without the need to write code, and that can be used on all (or most) chains (e.g. Ethereum, Binance, Solana, Hamony, etc.)?

Comment: Etherscan? (or any chain explorer that has the capacity to interact with smart contracts)

Comment: The thing is on some chains the block explorer doesn't allow to call contracts

Answer (score 0):

I was able to call a contract using zapper.fi.

I had staked ETH in Polywhale a rug pull website.  Zapper allowed me to call the contract without any code.  You just connect your wallet.  Click Farm/Stake/Vault on the left until you see your contract. Then click minus sign.